# Plotting solution of ODE in Maxima ("expression evalues to non-numeric value everywhere")

Tags: plot, maxima

I am solving for `w` in a 2nd order ODE using Maxima, it gives me some answer, but I am at loss as to how to plot the expression. The session looks like this:

```
eq: -E*(I0+I1*x)*'diff(w,x,2)=(f1/6)*x^3+(f0/2)*x^2+l*(f0/2+2*f1*l^2/3)*x;
sol2: ode2(eq,w,x);
solbc2: bc2(sol2,x=0,w=0,x=l,w=0);
solNum: subst([E=1,I0=1,I1=1,f0=1,f1=1,l=1],solbc2);
```

When I try to plot `solNum` with

```
plot(solNum,[x,0,1]);
```

I am getting

```
plot2d: expression evaluates to non-numeric value everywhere in plotting   range.
plot2d: nothing to plot.
```

I am Maxima beginner, I apologize if I overlooked something obvious. The tutorials I've crossed only show `plot2d` with an expression in it.

Comment: The ability to [plot implicit functions](https://maxima.sourceforge.io/docs/manual/maxima_64.html#index-plot2d) (equations) has now been added (between `5.43.2` and `5.45.1`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just plot [RHS of the solution](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/docs/manual/en/maxima_20.html#rhs).

```
eq: -E*(I0+I1*x)*'diff(w,x,2)=(f1/6)*x^3+(f0/2)*x^2+l*(f0/2+2*f1*l^2/3)*x;
sol2: ode2(eq,w,x);
solbc2: bc2(sol2,x=0,w=0,x=l,w=0);
solNum: subst([E=1,I0=1,I1=1,f0=1,f1=1,l=1],solbc2);

plot2d(rhs(solNum),[x,0,1]);
```