# Maxima - cannot plot my equation with plot2d, as "expression evaluates to non-numeric value everywhere in plotting range"

Tags: plot, maxima

With Maxima, I want to plot the value of a parameter depending on time by solving an equation for that specific parameter. I am new to Maxima and I already struggle with the beginning of my calculations. 
I use the following equation m which I want to solve for L:

```
m= m_I - (m_I-m_R)/(1+%e^(-s_R*(t-L)))
solve(%,L);
```

which gives me

```
L=(t*s_R-log(m_I/(m-m_R)-m/(m-m_R)))/s_R
```

as output. If I now assign values to all parameters except L and t

```
ev(%,m=0.5,m_I=1,m_R=0.1,s_R=0.01);
plot2d(%,[t,0,10]);
```

I get the error message

> "plot2d: expression evaluates to non-numeric value everywhere in
>   plotting range. plot2d: nothing to plot."

I know this is very basic but I still don't know what I am doing wrong. I also tried to use a function m(t):=... instead of an expression m=..., with the same result.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15619231/plotting-solution-of-ode-in-maxima-expression-evalues-to-non-numeric-value-eve?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `solve` has returned a list containing one element, which is an equation. In order to plot the result, you need to isolate the right-hand side of the equation, because that's what `plot2d` understands (it doesn't know what to do with the output of `solve` otherwise).

My advice is to get the part of the `solve` result that you want first, and then plot that. Something like:

```
solve (...);
my_equation : %[1];
my_equation_rhs : rhs(%);
plot2d (my_equation_rhs, [t, 0, 10]);
```

It is a deficiency of `plot2d` that it doesn't know what to do with the result of `solve`; sorry about that.

Comment: The ability to [plot implicit functions](https://maxima.sourceforge.io/docs/manual/maxima_64.html#index-plot2d) (equations) has been added between `5.43.2` and `5.45.1`, which is awesome.